# http_basic_authenticate_with is not working properly in rails 4.0 when we want to create comment why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security

I am following rails guide for 4.0 version, I am using example of PostController and CommentController.

When I am using

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", except: [:index, :show]
```

in postController then it is not asking the login authentication stuff and our comment is created.

But same way I defined

```
http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: :destroy
```

in commentController and it is working, before deleting the commment it is asking authentication.

So, I want that authentication should work before comment creation also. I checked my rails version is 4.0 and ruby veresion is 1.9.3p194

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you entered your username and password the first time, your browser remember it in the current session (until you reload your Browser). Even when you refused to save your password. I use Firefox and I have the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Mabybe `http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secret", only: [:destroy, :create]` ??